# jQuery sortable - move item between 2 connected lists keeping count

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two list with 6 items, connectedWith a class of `.connectedSortable` When I move an item between the two lists, it gets appended to the target list, and removed from the source list. So now we have a list with 5 items, and a list with 7 items. How can the items remain 6 items per list, and we just move the top most in the target list to the first list (automatically rearranges itself in the same order as if it were one list)?

```
<ul class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
</ul>

<ul class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
</ul>

$( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

**To clarify:** The number of lists may be 2 or more. But what I am after is the fixed number of 6 items per list and correct automatic rearrangement as sortable does if it were single list. An example is if you move item 3 from list1 to list2 after item 4, then the outcome should be this:

```
<ul class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
</ul>

<ul class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RjV5/)

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want? If you drag `Item 3` from source list to target list, what would you want to see appear in both lists?

Comment: @mccannf Just clarified the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `receive` option. The following code assumes that there are a number of `<ul>` elements, with `id="ulX"`, where `X` is an integer sequence starting from 1:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        receive: function (event, ui) {
             var targetul = $(ui.item).parent().attr("id");
             var targetno = parseInt(targetul.split("ul")[1]);
             var sourceul = $(ui.sender).attr("id");
             var sourceno = parseInt(sourceul.split("ul")[1]);

             if (sourceno > targetno)
                 rippleUp(targetno, sourceno);
             else
                 rippleDown(targetno, sourceno);

        }
    }).disableSelection();
});


function rippleUp(start, end) {
    for (var i=start;i<end;i++) {
         $("#ul"+i+" > li").last().prependTo("#ul"+(i+1));
    }
}

function rippleDown(start, end) {
    for (var i=start;i>end;i--) {
         $("#ul"+i+" > li").first().appendTo("#ul"+(i-1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. After dragging a few items around, it seems to not work properly (using the top one with weirdness is fine, as it should have 6 items). For example, from the above scenario, after moving the 3rd item back to its position in list1, the order gets messed up. Everything from that point on messes up the order. If there is also a 3rd+ list, the code doesn't work with that (it adds/removes items, ignoring the 6 item limit). Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5RjV5/7/

Comment: @Wonka - sorry didn't see the requirement for 3+ lists. Edited - will support that now with ui.sender. However, it seems to work as per your question now. What do you mean "order gets messed up"? If you drag any item from one list to another, the *first* item in the target list gets appended to the source list, right? Do you have another requirement for dragging items back to their original list?

Comment: Hmmm... Try dragging item 3 from list 3 to list 2 under item 3, this should cause item 5 of list 2 to be the first li in list 3 but it doesn't work as intended. It instead moved item 1 from list 2 to the last position in list 3. I came up with this last night, which works perfectly, except it only supports 3 lists. I was looking for a solution like yours that would work with x number of lists: http://jsfiddle.net/5RjV5/8/

Comment: Ah - now I understand what you're trying to do. Updated code. Will work with any number of `<ul>` elements