# revert manual changes to 2 connected jquery ui sortable lsts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have multiple jquery ui sortable lists that are connected and get balanced manually to N number of items whenever items are received by one list - just like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754827/27497

However, it appears that when you manually move items between lists (using jquery's .appendTo() or .prependTo()), these changes aren't detected by the jquery ui sortable library, and thus when you use the "cancel" command to revert the state, the manually moved items aren't placed back into their original list.

Is there a proper way to manually move an item from one list to another so that the sortable library is able to move the item back when you call $(".my-lists-selector").sortable("cancel");

Here is an example of how the items don't revert when you call .sortable("cancel") - just click the red cancel button after moving items from one list to another: http://jsfiddle.net/SUffL/3/

```
   $(function() {
    $( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var ul1 = $("#ul1 li");
            var ul2 = $("#ul2 li");
            var ul3 = $("#ul3 li");

            checkul1(ul1, ul2, ul3);
            checkul2(ul1, ul2, ul3);
            checkul3(ul1, ul2, ul3);
        }
    }).disableSelection();

  $("#cancel-btn").click(function(){
    $(".connectedSortable").sortable("cancel");
  });
});

function checkul1(ul1, ul2, ul3) {
    if (ul1.length > 5) {
        ul1.last().prependTo(ul2.parent());
    }
}

function checkul2(ul1, ul2, ul3) {
    if (ul2.length > 5) {
        if (ul1.length < 5) {
            ul2.first().appendTo(ul1.parent());
        } else {
            ul2.last().prependTo(ul3.parent());
        }
    }
}

function checkul3(ul1, ul2, ul3) {
    if (ul3.length > 5) {
        ul3.first().appendTo(ul2.parent());
        checkul2(ul1, ul2, ul3);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your relevant code otherwise how can you expect someone would be able to help you?

Comment: also create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: now updated with a jsfiddle, and code showing how one call .sortable("cancel") on that original example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that stores the manually moved item along with list it started in and list it is moved to. Within the `receive` event handler the 2 lists are available as `ui.sender` and `this`. I created a simple `balanceLists` function to handle the manual move and the cancel of same

```
$(function () {

  var listChange = {
    startList: null,
    item: null,
    endList: null
  }
  $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: function (event, ui) {     
      listChange = {
        startList: ui.sender,
        item: ui.item,
        endList: $(this)
      }

      balanceLists($(this), ui.sender)

    }
  }).disableSelection();

  $("#cancel-btn").click(function () {
    if (listChange.item) {
      balanceLists(listChange.startList, listChange.endList)
      $(".connectedSortable").sortable("cancel").sortable("refresh");
      listChange.item=null;
    }
  });
});


function balanceLists($from, $to) {
  $to.append($from.find('li').last())

}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SUffL/8/

This allows to undo one move with cancel button.

Comment: tried using all combinations of those two calls without any luck.

Comment: might be better to store the state of lists manually. Is your expectation of `Cancel` button just to cancel the last move?

Comment: updated a solution that I think does what you want based on cancel only supporting one move